# ION Range Slider triggering multiple times If axios is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, ion-range-slider

When Axios is used in the OnFinish method, It is triggered multiple times. If I don't use Axios, there seems to be no problem. You can check the sample code below.

When Axios is not used.

```
   $("#input-range-sound-output").ionRangeSlider({
            onFinish: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```

[image]

When Axios is used

```
   $("#input-range-sound-output").ionRangeSlider({
        onFinish: function (data) {
            search.getProductsByFilter(); //AXIOS
        }
    });
```

[image]

Is there anyone that faced the problem above or has any ideas about how to solve it?

Comment: I found the cause of the problem. Swal is corrupting ION. If the SWAL loader is used, ION's onFinish event is always triggered.